# hibernate Operand should contain 1 column(s) y controll de null

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Estoy intentando hacer un filtro de búsqueda de productos, con lo que cada vez que se envía me pueden llegar los campos rellenos o nulos (algunos de estos son listas).

El problema es que cuando las listas tienen mas de un valor me da el siguiente error *hibernate Operand should contain 1 column(s)*. El problema es que necesito mantener el control de null para seguir buscando productos cuando alguno de sus valores me llegue nulo

La query que tengo montada actualmente es la siguiente

```
    @Query("select t from producto t where ((:categoria) is null or t.categoria in (:categoria)) and ((:precio) is null or  t.precio in (:precio)) and ((:municipio) is null or t.municipio = (:municipio))")
    public Page<producto> findAllProductosByFiltro(Pageable pageable, @Param("categoria")List<String> categorias,@Param("precio")List<String>precio,@Param("municipio") String municipio );
```

Y el json que espera recibir sería algo como:

```
{"categorias":["deporte", "tecnologia"],"presupuestos":["5€ - 15€"],"municipio":"nombreMunicipio"}
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: Hacer más de una pregunta por publicación es motivo de cierre. Es más, hay un motivo de cierre predefinido para publicaciones con muchas preguntas. Podrías eliminar una de las dos preguntas en tu publicación por favor?

Comment: por favor intenta con `@Query("select t from producto t where (coalesce(:categoria,null) is null or t.categoria in :categoria) and (coalesce(:precio,null) is null or  t.precio in :precio) and (coalesce(:municipio,null) is null or t.municipio = :municipio)")` y si funciona me avisas para darte la explicacion. saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas Al final conseguí resolver el problema con la función coalesce de hibernate que me facilitó **Ruslan López**. Adjunto su respuesta

> por favor intenta con @Query("select t from producto t where (coalesce(:categoria,null) is null or t.categoria in :categoria) and (coalesce(:precio,null) is null or  t.precio in :precio) and (coalesce(:municipio,null) is null or t.municipio = :municipio)")

Muchas gracias!